# Undefined method why?

Tags: java

Please help. I don't know why such a single method make error including undefined method for this type of class. I used  like this before with no error. I define two class one containing the method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class f1 {
    private int h;

    public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Set health");
         h = sc.nextInt();
         l(h);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class f2 {

    private int health;
    public void l(int h)
    {
        health = h;
        System.out.println(health);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look up instance methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
   public void main(String args[])
   {
        System.out.println("Set health");
        h = sc.nextInt();
        l(h);  //Root of your problems
   }
```

method `l()` is undefined under the scope of class `f1`. Meaning that `f1` do not understand what is `l()`. To let `class f1` know what is it, you can:

```
   public void main(String args[])
   {
        System.out.println("Set health");
        h = sc.nextInt();

        f2 obj = new f2();  //create an object of class f2
        obj.l(h);  //Now they know l() comes from an f2 object
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax "l(h)" indicates that you are calling a method, so the compiler knows that much.  If the compiler says "undefined method", then either it is spelled wrong (not your case) or it is not defined in a (or the) place where the compiler expects it.

Your method l(int) is in a different class.  How would the compiler know to locate it there, and not in some other class in your program?

In the future: when you have an error message, post it; in this case, I know just what the error message looks like, so it wasn't necessary, but in general on this forum it is not enough to say what the message says, you should post the text directly.

Comment: what can i do ? the exact message is "The method l(int) is undefined for the type of f1

Comment: Well, you can look at where you think l(int) is defined, and look at the error message to see where the compiler thinks it's defined.  I'm being purposely incomplete; if you cannot get the answer to this on your own, you are going to have a very difficult time getting through any kind of programming course, self-taught or otherwise.

Comment: self-taught I think .I  had forgotten to use an object. An user remined me .